# Problems with new Android project

Tags: android

I tried to uninstall and re install the SDK and ADT and now when I'm trying to create a new project with the ADT on Build Target it notifies "No target available".

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To develop an Android application, you also need to download at least one Android platform and the SDK Platform-tools

Have you done that? If no, open the Android SDK and AVD Manager (in Eclipse, Window menu) and download an Android platform. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#AddingComponents).

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I noticed that eclipse was unawware of the ADT.